# react-native How to open local file url using Linking?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-linking, rn-fetch-blob

I'm using the following code to download a file (can be a PDF or a DOC) and then opening it using Linking.

```js
const { dirs } = RNFetchBlob.fs;
let config = {
    fileCache : true,
    appendExt : extension,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
        useDownloadManager : false,
        notification : false,
        title : 'File',
        description : 'A file.',
        path: `${dirs.DownloadDir}/file.${extension}`,
    },
};
RNFetchBlob.config(config)
    .fetch(
        method,
        remoteUrl,
        APIHelpers.getDefaultHeaders()
    )
    .then((res) => {
        let status = res.info().status;
        if (status == 200) {
            Linking.canOpenURL(res.path())
                .then((supported) => {
                    if (!supported) {
                        alert('Can\'t handle url: ' + res.path());
                    } else {
                        Linking.openURL(res.path())
                            .catch((err) => alert('An error occurred while opening the file. ' + err));
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => alert('The file cannot be opened. ' + err));
        } else {
            alert('File was not found.')
        }
    })
    .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
        alert('There was some error while downloading the file. ' + errorMessage);
    });
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

**An error occurred while opening the file. Error: Unable to open URL:**
**file:///Users/abhishekpokhriyal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E2A9C16-0222-40A6-8C1C-EC174B6EE9E8/data/Containers/Data/Application/A37B9D69-583D-4DC8-94B2-0F4AF8272310/Documents/RNFetchBlob_tmp/RNFetchBlobTmp_o259xexg7axbwq3fh6f4.pdf**

*I need to implement the solution for both iOS and Android.*

Comment: are you solve it?

Comment: @OliverD not yet. eagerly waiting for an answer.

Comment: If storing the file in local is not necessary, why not use `remoteUrl` in `Linking.openURL`?
`Linking.openURL(remoteUrl).then(...).catch(...)` opens your pdf in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do so is by using [react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer) package.

It allows you to Prompt the user to choose an app to open the file with (if there are multiple installed apps that support the mimetype).

```js
import FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';

const path = // absolute-path-to-my-local-file.
FileViewer.open(path, { showOpenWithDialog: true })
.then(() => {
    // success
})
.catch(error => {
    // error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally did this by replacing Linking by the package [react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer).

In my `APIHelpers.js`:

```js
async getRemoteFile(filePath, extension, method = 'GET') {
    const remoteUrl = `${API_BASE_URL}/${encodeURIComponent(filePath)}`;
    const { dirs } = RNFetchBlob.fs;
    let config = {
        fileCache : true,
        appendExt : extension,
        addAndroidDownloads : {
            useDownloadManager : false,
            notification : false,
            title : 'File',
            description : 'A file.',
            path: `${dirs.DownloadDir}/file.${extension}`,
        },
    };

    return new Promise(async (next, error) => {
        try {
            let response = await RNFetchBlob.config(config)
                .fetch(
                    method,
                    remoteUrl,
                    this.getDefaultHeaders()
                );
            next(response);
        } catch (err) {
            error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

In my `Actions.js`

```js
export function openDocument(docPath, ext) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchingFile());
        APIHelpers.getRemoteFile(docPath, ext).then(async function(response) {
            dispatch(successFetchingFile());
            let status = response.info().status;
            if (status == 200) {
                const path = response.path();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    FileViewer.open(path, {
                        showOpenWithDialog: true,
                        showAppsSuggestions: true,
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            dispatch(errorOpeningFile(error));
                        });
                }, 100);
            } else {
                dispatch(invalidFile());
            }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                dispatch(errorFetchingFile(err));
            });
    }
}
```

In my `Screen.js`

```js
import { openDocument } from 'path/to/Actions';

render() {
    return <Button
                title={'View file'}
                onPress={() => this.props.dispatchOpenDocument(doc.filepath, doc.extension)}
            />;
}
.
.
.
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    dispatchOpenDocument: (docPath, ext) => openDocument(docPath, ext),
}
```

Comment: can i open folder? i mean i want to open download folder  in my app

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading it from the web? I can see the pdf path is attached at the end of the error path.
**For web URLs, the protocol ("http://", "https://") must be set accordingly!**

Try to append appropriate schemes to your path. Check it out from the link mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with 'rn-fetch-blob'

```
RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(fileLocation, mimeType);
```